# Adding text alongside images in markdown in Github

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, markdown, editing

**Context :-**

So, I am trying to write readme.md for my latest github repo.

**Issue :-**

I am trying to add images in .md file which looks like conversations.

I am trying to achieve something like this. [I am able to do this in mac-pages]

[image]

But what it is coming for me is this in vscode

[image]

Can anyone help me out and tell me how can I include images in a way that I should be able to write code from the upwards? Like first image?

Comment: try: create a table of 2 columns and add text and image in separate columns

Comment: @rioV8 .. Tried that out .. looks okay but still table rows and columns are showing up

Comment: Can you add a `<style>` tag in markdown and just remove the borders of the table

Comment: Github is not accepting CSS changes....

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<img valign="middle" src="link_to_your_image"  /> My Text
```